# Pretty url with Hippo CMS

Tags: java, hippocms

I created a sitemapItem as :

1. jcr configuration: `doto/_default_/default/_any_`
2. hst:**relativecontentpath**: doto/detail/**${3}**
3. **my url**: todo/detail/**todo-item4-from-cms-editor-user**

How can I get my title "**todo-item4-from-cms-editor-user**" from query string?

Is **${3} placeholder** my title "**todo-item4-from-cms-editor-user**" within query string?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see: http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/request-handling/sitemapitem-matching.html

I am going to assume that doto is meant to be todo and is a typo.

todo/*default*/default/*any*

will have 3 parameters, $1, $2, $3

todo/detail/todo-item4-from-cms-editor-user

This has only two unknowns. todo will be matched with todo (if doto was meant it won't match at all).

so todo-item4-from-cms-editor-user is actually $2.

Comment: Ok thanks, now 
http://localhost:8080/site/todo/detail?titleId=todo-item1 
work fine for me

I'm sorry, I was not clear... but I need to convert 

http://localhost:8080/site/todo/detail?titleId=todo-item1
as
http://localhost:8080/site/todo/detail/todo-item1,
http://localhost:8080/site/todo/detail/todo-item2,
http://localhost:8080/site/todo/detail/todo-item3 
and so on.

Is there in HippoCMS  a mechanism that describes an url as /todo/detail/{titleId}, where titleId is dinamic?

Similar to spring restful url
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-rest-hello-world-example/

Comment: The mailing list already gave an answer but I am including it here for posterity.

What you could do is add it to your component

just add the hst:parameternames value and give it a name, e.g. "item", then add hst:parametervalues and add ${2} (if you want to get the second segment)

Then in your component code you can just use: 
getComponentParameter("item")

And you should get the value of ${2} as a result.

see also: http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/component-development/hstcomponent-parametersinfo-annotation.html

Comment: Or perhaps I completely misunderstood you and what you want is:
http://urlrewriter.forge.onehippo.org/index.html

as stated by Jeroen Reijn on the mailing list.

Comment: Oh well, I really need to an url-rewriting mechanism.
Anyway now I have clear also the sitemap argument
Ok...Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Your **todo-item4-from-cms-editor-user** is actually ${2}